# Express loads my React application no matter what route I use, what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to use the json at /species, however, express seems to always be loading the react app no matter what route I use. Can anyone figure out what's wrong? Here's my server.js file:

```
const app = require('express')(); 
const cors = require('cors') 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const path = require('path'); 
const express = require('express');

//Enable CORS app.use(cors());

const species = [   {
    name: 'mallard'   } ];

const sightings = [   {
    id: '1',
    species: 'gadwall',
    description: 'All your ducks are belong to us',
    dateTime: '2016-10-01T01:01:00Z',
    count: 1   },   {
    id: '2',
    species: 'lesser scaup',
    description: 'This is awesome',
    dateTime: '2016-12-13T12:05:00Z',
    count: 5   } ];

//Enable CORS app.use((req, res, next) => {   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");   next(); });

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/sightings', (req, res) => {   
res.json(sightings); });

app.post('/sightings', (req, res) => {   
req.body.id = (sightings.length + 1).toString();   
sightings.push(req.body);   
res.json(req.body); });

app.get('/species', (req, res) => {   res.json(species); });


app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './react-front/build')));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {   response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './react-front/build', 'index.html')); });

const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 8081; const server
= app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening  port %s", port); });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Some more information about what/why you're trying to accomplish, and what you've tried so far, would be helpful.  There are [some tips here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about posting questions.

Comment: Looks like you are duplicating sending static assets on this line: app.get(‘*’,...). Try without it.

Comment: @Splitty That didn't change anything actually. It's still rendering the react app on any route. I'm trying to render information from the jsons on the localhost to the react app.

Comment: It seems that issue has got something to do with service worker that was included with create-react-app

Comment: Are you running "yarn start" with create react app?

Comment: @Joshua Underwood I'm running npm start. I was able to render data from the json now, however, I'm still unable to display it on my browser unless I clean service worker.

Comment: Your service worker shouldn't be starting if you're running your code locally. Furthermore, you shouldn't be running a service worker on the server pulling data. You SHOULD have one server that renders your React application and another server for making API calls. Service worker or no service worker if you want to produce a production ready application its better to split them up.

Comment: @JoshuaUnderwood Thank you for the input, I appreciate it. I will split them up.

Comment: It is loading react, because you are telling it to. This is loading react is it not? `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './react-front/build')));`

Comment: @AdamPatterson Yes it does, however I thought it would not affect the other routes I have set up for the apis.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this problem by separating the routes that you want to use React with.

For instance, you could write a new Express module for those apps that you want to use with React and export it:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

// Use 'react-front/build' for router, but not
// your main Express application.
router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './react-front/build')));

router.get('/something', function(req, res) {
  // Do something here
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then add something like the following to your express app

```
// Require the module
const reactRouter = require('./path/to/router');

app.use(reactRouter);
```